# Kernel Oops page fault error codes for ARM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, fault

What does error code after Oops give information about the panic in arm ex.
`Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP`
what 17 give information in this case.
In x86 it represents -

- `bit 0 ==    0: no page found  1: protection fault`
- `bit 1 ==   0: read access     1: write access`
- `bit 2 ==   0: kernel-mode access  1: user-mode access`
- `bit 3 ==              1: use of reserved bit detected`
- `bit 4 ==              1: fault was an instruction fetch`

But i am not able to find any information in arm.

Thanks
Shunty

Comment: Did you use Google? I tried "linux kernel oops arm" and got lots of hits.

Comment: I am asking what number 17 give information about the page fault in arm, in x86 number after oops is 0X0000 where each bit signifies the fault.

Answer (score 2):

What you printed above as description of bits is page fault descriptions, not Oops faults.

See Linux's [oops-tracing](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/oops-tracing.txt?h=v4.9) for more information on looking for Linux crash analysis.

Below is how your `Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP` [arch/arm/kernel/traps.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c#L242):

```
    #define S_PREEMPT " PREEMPT"
    ...
    #define S_SMP " SMP"
    ...
    printk(KERN_EMERG "Internal error: %s: %x [#%d]" S_PREEMPT S_SMP S_ISA "\n", str, err, ++die_counter);
```

Page faults doesn't need to crash the kernel, as well as not all kernel crashes are page faults. So there is a high chance `Oops: 17` is not related to page faults at all. (and as a bonus my wild guess is it is about scheduling / just sounds familiar to me.)

Comment: What I printed is page fault description for x86 arch, i want to know the same for ARM.

Comment: @shunty So you want to know the page fault descriptions for arm arch? Why don't you ask so? Why you mention about Oops codes?

Comment: In X86 if page fault happen value after Oops: 0000 will give the information about the page fault, is it same for arm?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're asking about the **ARM Fault Status Register (FSR)** bits. I looked up the kernel code (arch/arm/mm/fault.c) and found that this is what is actually passed as a parameter to the Oops code:

```
    static void
    __do_kernel_fault(struct mm_struct *mm, unsigned long addr, unsigned int fsr,
              struct pt_regs *regs)
    {
    [...]
        pr_alert("Unable to handle kernel %s at virtual address %08lx\n",
             (addr < PAGE_SIZE) ? "NULL pointer dereference" :
             "paging request", addr);

        show_pte(mm, addr);
        die("Oops", regs, **fsr**);
   [...]
   }
```

So, anyway, this I traced to the FSR register on the ARM(v4 and above?) MMU:

Source: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438d/BABFFDFD.html

```
...
    [3:0]   FS[3:0] 
    Fault Status bits. This field indicates the type of exception generated. Any encoding not listed is reserved:
    b00001
       Alignment fault.
    b00100
       Instruction cache maintenance fault[a].
    b01100
       Synchronous external abort on translation table walk, 1st level.
    b01110
       Synchronous external abort on translation table walk, 2nd level.
    b11100
       Synchronous parity error on translation table walk, 1st level.
    b11110
       Synchronous parity error on translation table walk, 2nd level.
    b00101
       Translation fault, 1st level.
    b00111
       Translation fault, 2nd level.
    b00011
       Access flag fault, 1st level.
    b00110
       Access flag fault, 2nd level.
    b01001
       Domain fault, 1st level.
    b01011
       Domain fault, 2nd level.
    b01101
       Permission fault, 1st level.
    b01111
       Permission fault, 2nd level.
    b00010
       Debug event.
    b01000
       Synchronous external abort, non-translation.
    b11001
       Synchronous parity error on memory access.
    b10110
       Asynchronous external abort.
    b11000
       Asynchronous parity error on memory access.
```

...

Disclaimer: I don't know whether this info is still relevant; the doc states it's for the ARM Cortex A15 and the page is marked as Superseded.

Could see this page also:
[ARM926EJ-S Fault address and fault status registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0198e/Babgbhee.html)

Comment: Also, fyi, the FAR (Fault Address Register) holds the faulting virtual address, equivalent to CR2 on Intel MMUs.